# I want to install @angular/google-maps npm Package in angular 16.2.12 but "npm install @angular/google-maps" this is not working/ tell me other query

Tags: angularjs

PS D:\birlasoft\myapp> npm install @angular/google-maps
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: myapp@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @angular/google-maps@17.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm ERR!   @angular/google-maps@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\sakshis6\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sakshis6\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-24T11_00_49_806Z-debug-0.log

i want to install @angular/google-maps npm Package in angular 16.2.12.